# signInWithRedirect with GoogleAuthProvider gets white screen on safari when I select the account manually

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, safari, handler

When I want to login by google ( in my Angular 6 web app ) in Safari  from ios (11.4):

1st=> I put email and password manually and then I get a pretty white screen with the url __/auth/handler

2nd=> I try to login again and then I load the web again and I choose the account stored ( yes , the account has been stored from the previous action ) and then no problem at all.

Every new customer has to login twice to get into and this situation maybe is not very good.

On firefox and chrome no problem at all : just safari.

Any ideas or suggestions are very welcome.

```
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router   ) {}

  googleLogin() {
    const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.setCustomParameters({
      prompt: 'select_account'
    });
    this.afAuth.auth.languageCode = 'en';
    return this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(
      x => {
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider)
                   .catch(() => this.router.navigate(['/']));
      }
    ); 
  }
```

1st => [Signin Google manually email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aaAK.png)

2nd => [Signin Google manually password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91EgG.png)

3rd => [Auth handler white screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Cmq.jpg)

4th => [Signin Google when account stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEtzF.jpg)

When I inspect with safari developer tool on Mac then I see the following:
can't close the window since it was not opened by javascript

[Cant close the window since javascript su puta madre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFepf.jpg)